# Problem after i publish the App to Azure Web Site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

My app is working fine locally but corrupted when deploying the published version to production (Azure Web App).

The system can't run in production. I'm getting the following error after your recent upgrade to In-Process mode:

> HTTP Error 500.30 - ANCM In-Process Start Failure

Logs are written empty on the Logs folder.

Please note that I use same configuration file for the last version and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

This two lines was missing in the startup.cs

```
services.AddRazorPages();
services.AddControllersWithViews();
```

Comment: Hi, please don't forget to accept yourself solution as the answer of this question. Thank you for your work. This will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of .NET Core your app is developed? Is it 3.1? Azure App service doesn't support .NET Core 3.1 SDK out of the box in all regions, either you need to install the extensions, or you need to move your app to a supported region or you need to use a Web App using Docker. If it is an Azure app service supported SDK, then try updating the web.config file, like this.

Modify the following section.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

To the following.

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
    <AspNetCoreModuleName>AspNetCoreModule</AspNetCoreModuleName>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

Source : [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.2/2.2-known-issues.md)